# calling stored procedure for different parameters postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure in postgres to populate some statistics about phone number

```
create or replace function PhoneNumberSummary(
    phonenumber varchar(255), 
    fromperiod timestamp without time zone, 
    toperiod timestamp without time zone
)
```

So I want to call same procedure for different phone numbers. Can I do this in single call by some redesigning my stored procedure, I mean variable parameter list.

Is there any efficient way to use same stored procedure?

Comment: Function can be called upon any table's column untill the input data type is matching

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that do I understand clearly your question.

Basically, it depends on return of your function, and where is the variable parameter list. 
In example, your variable parameter list is on an table `xyz` like this.

```
phonenumber | time_start          | time_end
123         | 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | 2018-01-01 13:50:00
456         | 2018-01-01 20:00:00 | 2018-01-01 20:50:00
```

You can call your function as

`SELECT (PhoneNumberSummary(t.phonenumber, t.time_start, t.time_end)).* FROM xyz t`

Hopefully my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the input parameters as arrays, that way you can use a function to insert a number of rows in one `INSERT` statement.

You could construct a multi-row `INSERT`-Statement and execute it with `EXECUTE`.

I am not sure if that will speed up performance, but you can try and run a performance test.